# Choose between multiple options with defined probability

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, algorithm

I have a scenario where I need to show a different page to a user for the same url based on a probability distribution,

so for e.g. for 3 pages the distribution might be

```
page 1 - 30% of all users
page 2 - 50% of all users
page 3 - 20% of all users
```

**When deciding what page to load for a given user, what technique can I use to ensure that the overall distribution matches the above?**

I am thinking I need a way to choose an object at "random" from a set X { x1, x2....xn } except that instead of all objects being equally likely the probability of an object being selected is defined beforehand.

---

Thanks for the input everyone, after doing some prototyping, this is what I ended up using

```
private static int RandomIndexWithPercentage(Random random, int[] percentages) {
    if (random == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("random");
    }

    if (percentages == null || percentages.Length == 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("percentages cannot be null or empty", "percentages");
    }

    if(percentages.Sum() != 100) {
        throw new ArgumentException("percentages should sum upto 100");
    }

    if (percentages.Any(n => n < 0)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("percentages should be non-negative");
    }

    var randomNumber = random.Next(100);
    var sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < percentages.Length; ++i) {
        sum += percentages[i];
        if (sum > randomNumber) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    //This should not be reached, because randomNumber < 100 and sum will hit 100 eventually
    throw new Exception("Unexpected");
}
```

Comment: How strict is your use of the term "ensure" here?  Obviously if we just pick numbers at random you're not ensuring that 30% of your users will land on Page1 - you're merely stacking the odds in favor of that outcome.  

Is the complexity here that you have to guarantee that for any set of N users, the page distribution will absolutely be within a very small margin of error of your target percentages?

Comment: That's a good point Andrew, this test runs for a couple of days so I don't need a tight margin for any set of N users. Is there an algorithm that will provide minimum variation from this distribution for all values of N?

Comment: You could adapt the algorithm to bias itself depending on which users are on which pages, but it would be a lot more overhead for very little payoff. The best way to do that would be not use random numbers at all - if 3 users are viewing page one, 4 are viewing page two, and 2 are viewing page three, place the next user on page two (obviously). If another user comes, place him in page two as well, because it's the largest pool - so a single additional user there would impact your overall distribution the least.

Comment: Andrew and cyclotis04 are right. Going probability wise won't give you what you want (if you want exact distribution). Say you just had 2 pages and wanted to get 50% users on pg1 and 50% on pg2. If you selected pages randomly (with 50%) chance, then after n trials, the expected value of |number_pg1 - number_pg2| is sqrt(n). Not zero as you think it would. Check out 1-d random walk. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk

Comment: Of course, if you are willing to live with approximate distribution of users, then this should be fine for large number of page serves. For instance, in the above 2 page case, for n=10000 we get expected 4950 vs 5050. For n=100, it becomes 45 vs 55.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate a number 0-9. If the number is less than 3, give them page one. If it's less than 8, give them page two, or else give them page three.

---

Some code, to get you started:

```
private int ChoosePage()
{
    int[] weights = new int[] { 3, 5, 2 };
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < weights.Length; i++)
        sum += weights[i];
    int selection = (new Random()).Next(sum);
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < weights.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        count += weights[i];
        if (selection < count)
            return i;
    }
    return weights.Length - 1;
}
```

Note that weights doesn't have to add up to anything in particular. If `sum` = 100, then `weight[i]` is th percent chance of getting page `i`. If it doesn't, however, it's just relative - if `weight[i]` is twice `weight[j]`, then page `i` will get twice as many hits as page `j`. This is nice because you can arbitrarily increase or decrease page traffic without recalculating anything. Alternatively, you could make sure the sum is always `N`, and hardcode `N` in, rather than summing all the values every time. There are a lot more optimizations you could do, I'm sure.

Comment: I think number between 0-100 would be better to take care of percentages like 19 which would end up in decimal land if i try to translate to the 0-10 range.

Comment: See my edit - all percentages are converted to weights, anyways, so whether it's out of 10 or 100 is irrelevant, if that's how you choose to do it. (If you need %s, then yes - stick with 100.)

Comment: Also note you shouldn't do `(new Random())` for every random number - it should probably be initialized once then stored in a class variable somewhere.

Comment: Yup, I saw the issue with (new Random()) when testing, so I take that as a parameter to the function now and initialize that at a global level for the entire run. Thanks.

Comment: In case there are multiple entities all with 0 weights this would always return the last entry and not in a round-robin fashion.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and works carefully.

```
public static int GetRandomIndexByPercent(params byte[] percentages)
    {
        int randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, percentages.Sum(a => a) + 1);

        for (int sum = 0, i = 0; i < percentages.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sum += percentages[i];
            if (randomNumber <= sum) return i;
        }

        return percentages.Length - 1;
    }
```

Also for test it, you can use this code:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            var items = new int[] { 40, 20, 10, 30 };
            var items2 = new int[items.Length];

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
                items2[GetRandomIndexByPercent(items)]++;

            for (int i = 0; i < items2.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(items[i] + " > " + (items2[i] / 1000.0));

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```